# What are the downsides of a mutating state in React?

Tags: reactjs

I have a React app with a top-level component and a number of nested sub-components. The top-level component is the only component with state. That state takes the form a single variable:

```
this.state = {
  g: new BlackJackGame()
}
```

g contains a complex data structure:

```
class BlackJackGame{
   playerHand = []; 
   dealerHand = [];
   deck = [ /* initially 52 cards * ]; 
   ....
}
```

g also contains three methods that *mutate* it's state in-place:

```
g.deal(): take 4 cards from deck and add them to playerHand and dealerHand (2 cards each)
g.hit(): take 1 card from deck and add it to playerHand
g.stay(): take cards from deck and add to dealerHand while dealerHand's points < 17.
```

onDealClick looks like this:

```
onDealClick = event => {
  this.state.g.deal();
  this.setState({ g: this.state.g });
};
```

I know the recommended approach is to *not* mutate state. But the truth is, this works perfectly well. And I have used this pattern many times. And it seems to work just fine. As far as I can tell, these are the only downsides:

1. If I needed to to perform dirty checking in shouldComponentUpdate (I don't) I would have to use deepEquals instead of pointer comparison.
2. If I needed Undo (I don't) it would be harder to implement.
3. Switching to Redux might be painful, since Redux would force me to use a functional, immutable style rather than an OO style.

Question: Are there any other downsides that I am missing?

Comment: By manipulating this.state directly you are circumventing React’s state management, which can be potentially dangerous as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made.

Comment: How so? What code would reproduce this behavior?

Answer (score 0):

When calling `setState` to update the state, the component automatically invokes `shouldComponentUpdate` and rerenders when needed.

If you mutate the state directly, the change is not automatically reflected in the UI, until you force the rendering somehow. This is circumventing React state management, implementing your own state management.

React is simple and very flexible, therefore your way will work. I cannot recommend it though.

Comment: Can you give a specific scenario where this has a negative impact?

Comment: @DaveFord For example, you cannot implement `shouldComponentUpdate` because `nextState` and `this.state` will point to the same object, therefore they will be the same and you won't know what has changed.