# How do I setState of a deeply nested property in React?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to increment the tally property of a given habit, in this context I'm targeting tally: 4. On a related note, I'm open to suggestions for better ways of structuring my data.

```
class App extends Component {
  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      displayedHabit: "Exercise",
      currentUser: "Achilles",
      userList: [
          {
            user: "Achilles",
            id: 0,
            habits: [
            {
              habit: "Exercise",
              tally: 123
            },
            {
              habit: "Eat Vegetables",
              tally: 4
            },

          ]
        }
      ]
    }
  }
```

Here is the implementation I've tried after searching for solutions. I don't believe it's working because assignments that use .find() that work after mounting are broken after I call the increment function through an event handler - leading me to believe .find() is no longer being called on an array.

```
increment = () => {
  let newCount = this.state.userList[0].habits[1].tally + 1
  this.setState({
    userList: {
      ...this.state.userList[0].habits[1],
      tally: newCount
    }
  })
}
```

Comment: I've just come across the immutability helper section and am attempting to apply it: https://reactjs.org/docs/update.html#update

...still open to suggestions.

Comment: Not totally clear what you're intentions are since you've hard-coded the first user and second habit. Also `userList` is an array but you assign it an object in `setState`. Could you make `userList` an object with ids as the keys for easy access?

Comment: It's hard-coded for now, while I'm setting up the functionality. I'm trying to update the tally of the second habit by +1. I could make it an object with keys, but that doesn't solve the problem of accessing deeply nested properties. Ideally, I could just do this.state.userList[0].habits[1].tally = this.state.userList[0].habits[1].tally + 1, but React doesn't allow for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In React, it's very important that you don't mutate your data structures. This essentially means that you have to copy the data structure at each level of your nested data. Since this is too much work, I suggest you use a library made for this purpose. I personally use [object-path-immutable](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path-immutable).

Example:

```
import {set} from 'object-path-immutable';

increment = ({userIndex, habitIndex}) => this.setState({
    userList: set(this.state.userList, [userIndex, 'habits', habitIndex, 'tally'], this.state.userList[userIndex].habits[habitIndex].tally + 1)
});
```

Comment: This is false. It's ok to mutate state.

Comment: No, it's NOT OK to mutate state. It's a pretty well-known fact about react. Just google react and immutability and you'll find all the info you need.

Comment: Provide some evidence to back up that statement. This isn't Redux.

Comment: https://reactjs.org/docs/optimizing-performance.html#the-power-of-not-mutating-data

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43839710/what-are-the-downsides-of-a-mutating-state-in-react

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32125063/reactjs-why-shouldnt-i-mutate-nested-state

Comment: just read the docs and other people's code. mutating state in react is asking for trouble

Comment: And redux didn't bring immutability to react. redux brought the single source of truth, reducers and action creators to react.

Comment: And while you might get away with mutating your state sometimes, if you keep doing it, you will eventually run into issues.

Comment: I'm not using PureComponent and neither is the OP. My code will never "run into issues" due to state mutation.

Comment: @RickJolly If you want to mutate you state, it's up to you, but you're doing a disservice to the community by spamming every answer with your nonsensical objections to immutability which is at the heart of react.

Comment: Stop the FUD and demonstrate how my code could ever break.

Comment: I tried all the solutions and earthling's was the only one I could get to work. Thanks for the help, everyone. Should I mark this as the answer or ...? I'm new to StackOverflow as an active participant.

Comment: @imperial_isms I'm glad to hear that my answer helped you. Since that is the case, yes, please mark it as the answer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend restructuring your data such that you have objects which actually map the data in accessible ways ie:

```
this.state = {
  displayedHabit: "Exercise",
  currentUser: "Achilles",
  userList: {
   "Achilles": { // Could also be id
        id: 0,
        habits: {
         "Exercise": 123,
         "EatVegetables": 4
      }
    }
  }
}
```

This would allow you to do something like

```
 increment = () => {
  const {userList} = this.state;
  this.setState({
    userList: {
      ...userList,
      Achilles: {
        ...userList.Achilles
        habits: {
          ...userlist.Achilles.habits
          'EatVegetables': userlist.Achilles.habits.EatVegetables + 1
        }
      }
    }
  })
}
```

This would be further simplified by using [object-path-immutable](https://github.com/mariocasciaro/object-path-immutable) which would allow you to do something simple like:

```
increment = () => {
  const {userList} = this.state;
  this.setState({
    userList: immutable.set(userList, 'Achilles.id.habits.Exercise', userList.Achilles.id.habits.Exercise + 1)
  })
}
```

In order to make this more generic though I would recommend doing what something similar to what earthling suggested:

import {set} from 'object-path-immutable';

```
incrementUserHabit = ({userIndex, habitIndex}) => this.setState({
    userList: set(this.state.userList, [userIndex, 'habits', habitIndex, 'tally'], this.state.userList[userIndex].habits[habitIndex].tally + 1)
});
```

This way your code is more reusable

Comment: Unless you have reason to use PureComponent, just mutate state and avoid the immutable dependency and complexity.

Answer (score -2):

Something like this?

```
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      userList: {
        '12': {
          name: 'Achilles',
          habits: {
            Exercise: {
              tally: 123
            },
            'Eat Vegetables': {
              tally: 231
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }

  inc() {
    const {userList} = this.state;
    userList['12'].habits['Exercise'].tally++;
    this.setState({userList});
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <h2>{this.state.userList['12'].habits['Exercise'].tally}</h2>
        <button onClick={() => this.inc()}>Increment</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
};
```

Play with it here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/10w0o6vn0l

Comment: Seems like your deconstruction line is only doing a shallow pull of userList, then you're changing state in the next line, then you're calling setState only part of the state, but not in an object (you maybe meant this.setState({userList}) (note the braces)).   But you're still modifying state, then covering for it, instead of creating a clone of state, modifying it, then setting state to that.

Comment: Was missing the curly braces. Fixed that, thanks. Not sure what you mean about the rest though. `this.setState({userList});` is a shortcut for `this.setState({userList: userList});`. Why would I want to clone the state?

Comment: Because modifying the state using assignment, which you do in the line before calling setState (you can verify by checking this.state.userList['12'].habits['Exercise'].tally is changed) which, according to what I've read, is a bad idea.   I admit to being relatively new to Redux, etc. but everything I've read says don't change state using assignment.

Comment: Care to provide a reason why state mutation is bad? This isn't Redux.

Comment: Think I'll let @earthling argue it in the other answer.

Comment: Well, he's incorrect. I'm not using PureComponent and neither is the OP.